# Initiate an array from Select-Object

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to generate an output string like `Item1, Item2`, that is joined with a comma separator. We do this by initiating an empty array in the `Select-Object -Property`.

Check this code:

```
$Test =  @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'Test'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'Test2'
    }
) | Select-Object -Property @{N = 'Problem'; E = { @() } },
@{N = 'EmployeeType'; E = { $null } }, *

foreach ($R in $Test) {
    $R.Problem += 'Item1'
    $R.Problem += 'Item2'
}


$Test | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Problem'; Expression = { $_.Problem -join "; " } }, * -ExcludeProperty Problem | fl
```

Result:

```
Problem      : Item1Item2
Name         : Test

Problem      : Item1Item2
Name         : Test2
```

Why is the property `Problem` concatenated as a `String` and not as an `Array`? How can it be converted to an `Array`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To instantiate an empty array in the expression of the calculated property, `@()` is not enough, because PowerShell will flatten that and it will become $null.

Use `,@()` instead

```
$Test =  @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'Test'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'Test2'
    }
) | Select-Object -Property @{N = 'Problem'; E = { ,@() } },
                            @{N = 'EmployeeType'; E = { $null } }, *

foreach ($R in $Test) {
    $R.Problem += 'Item1'
    $R.Problem += 'Item2'
}

$Test | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Problem'; Expression = { $_.Problem -join "; " } }, * -ExcludeProperty Problem | fl
```

Returns:

> ```
> Problem      : Item1; Item2
> EmployeeType : 
> Name         : Test
>
> Problem      : Item1; Item2
> EmployeeType : 
> Name         : Test2
> ```

Comment: Thank you Theo, that was exactly what we were looking for. Very strange why it gets flatten and why a comma is needed. But it works, thanks :)

Comment: @DarkLite1 Maybe not the best explanation, but here goes: PowerShell implicitly 'unboxes' a single-item array to a single object. The comma used as a unary operator, creates an array with just one member. In this case a 'wrapper array' with a single element that holds the empty array @(). Powershell unboxes the wrapper array, leaving you with the empty array you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that way to make an empty array didn't work.

```
PS C:\users\js> $test[0].problem.gettype()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $test[0].problem.gettype()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

PS C:\users\js> $test[0].problem -eq $null
True
```

By the way, using "+=" kills puppies.

Comment: Using `+=` only kills puppies when we're talking about large `arrays`. Not in the case of 5 elements or even less than 1000. The speed difference is neglect-able in these cases.